# What is the meaning of 着て行く?

Tags: meaning

I came upon these questions in my textbook. Here is the dialogue: 私は学校にせいふくを着て行きますが、何を着て行きますか。Now, I might assume 着て行く is close to 着ている as it still makes sense using the latter, but why is this verb used, assuming it acts as one, instead of the former?

Comment: About the other question that you've deleted: Please don't be afraid to ask more questions! We'll try to explain as best we can, but sometimes we just need more information from you. Hang in there! :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. I deleted the question because I was not going to get the answer that I wanted: whether my translation was correct or not.

Comment: For translation requests, transcriptions, proofreading or just general info, you can go to Reddit Translator, HiNative, etc. and get some good results ;)